# Android - Bringing a background app to the front

Tags: java, android

This code does not bring my app to the front when the user has pressed the home button and the app has receded to the background. There are no error messages:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Bringing app to foreground");
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), context.getPackageName() + ".MainActivity");
launchIntent.setComponent(componentName);
try {
     Log.d(TAG, "Launching intent");
     context.startActivity(launchIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

There are a number of questions asking the same thing and I seem to have tried all of the answers to no avail.

This is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mystuff.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.mystuff.myapp" />
    </queries>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: You cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare what would be the recommended procedure for bringing an app to the fore if indeed it is still running?

Comment: You could display a `Notification`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. That's the route I've chosen to go down which seems to be working. I assume I can't programmatically open the app because android wants to restrict that to a user click i.e. a notification click?

Comment: I think more specifically they want to prevent apps from interrupting the user. For example, if the user has a navigation app in the foreground, and your app decides it should take over the foreground, you might cause a car crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the insight. Makes total sense.